# Touch Behaviour of onMouseWheel on Mobile Devices - three.js

Tags: javascript, mobile

How to implement forward and backward scroll on Mobile Touch Devices or have the same behaviour as on Desktop (onMouseWheel)? Examples:

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xzwve647/

Desktop (animation work ok on Desktop back and forth)

**Mobile (animation doesn't work backwards - works only forward):**

```
function onTouchStart(event) {
        startY = event.touches[0].pageY;
    }
    function onTouchMove(event) {
        var delta = event.deltaY;
        if (event.deltaY > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
                mixers[i].update(clock.getDelta() * 5);
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
                mixers[i].update(clock.getDelta() * -5);
            }
        }
    }
```

Events listeners:

```
 window.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
 window.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false );
 window.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchMove, false );
```

```js
var container, stats, controls;
var camera, scene, renderer, light;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var mixer = [];

var mixers = [];

init();

animate();

function init() {

  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 100, 100);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
  light.position.set(0, 200, 0);
  scene.add(light);

  light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  light.position.set(0, 200, 100);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
  light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
  light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
  light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
  scene.add(light);

  // scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) );

  var grid = new THREE.GridHelper(2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000);
  grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
  grid.material.transparent = true;
  scene.add(grid);

  // model
  var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
  loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/fbx/Samba Dancing.fbx', function(object) {

    object.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);
    mixers.push(object.mixer);


    var action = object.mixer.clipAction(object.animations[0]);
    action.play();


    object.traverse(function(child) {

      if (child.isMesh) {

        child.castShadow = true;
        child.receiveShadow = true;

      }

    });
    object.position.y = 85;

    scene.add(object);

  });


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  window.addEventListener('mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false);
  window.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, false);
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);

  // stats
  stats = new Stats();
  container.appendChild(stats.dom);

}


function onResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}


function onMouseWheel(event) {


  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
      mixers[i].update(clock.getDelta() * 5);
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
      mixers[i].update(clock.getDelta() * -5);

    }
  }
}


function onTouchStart(event) {

  startY = event.touches[0].pageY;


}

function onTouchMove(event) {

  var delta = event.deltaY;

  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
      mixers[i].update(clock.getDelta() * 5);
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
      mixers[i].update(clock.getDelta() * -5);

    }
  }


}


function animate() {

  delta = clock.getDelta();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  stats.update();

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/inflate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/WebGL.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). If you can, please move your Fiddle contents into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) (or I can do it for you). Beyond that, it might help to simplify your question, like "I want X to happen when I make Y gesture, but Z happens instead."

Comment: Thank you, if you could please as it's labyrinthal here and it would take me some days to learn how the system works here. j

Comment: I have added your JSFiddle code as a (collapsed) snippet. It would be beneficial to learn how to do this, because it is the best way to keep all of the context related to the question inside the question itself.

Comment: @TheJim01. It's great that you wanted to be helpful but FYI, code put on JSFiddle has no license so technically it is illegal to repost it here without permission. I used to do the same thing until I was scolded on meta.

Comment: @gman Good old meta... I guess if SO wants askers to use snippets, they're going to have to up their game to make it more obvious than a tiny blurb on the help pages. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: is there a way to stop animation when scrolled to the top and then the same to the bottom? j

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect to happen with your code.

You probably want the `wheel` event, not the `mousewheel` event. `mousewheel` doesn't exist on Firefox.

There is no `event.deltaY` on a touch event. Touch events put there data on the `event.touches` array, one for each finger

If you had tried printing `event.deltaY` somewhere on the page or stepping through the code in a debugger [(run remotely)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) then it would have been obvious something is not right.

The code can by simpified by using a function. No need to repeat the loop 4 times.

```
function adjustMixers(deltaY) {
  const speed = deltaY > 0 ? 5 : -5;
  const amount = clock.getDelta() * speed;
  for (let i = 0; i < mixers.length; i++) {
    mixers[i].update(amount);
}

function onMouseWheel(event) {
  adjustMixers(event.deltaY);
}

let lastY;
function onTouchStart(event) {
  lastY = event.touches[0].pageY;
}

function onTouchMove(event) {
  const currentY = event.touches[0].pageY;
  const deltaY = currentY - lastY;
  lastY = currentY;
  adjustMixers(deltaY);
}
```

Finally you can prevent the browser from doing its default (moving the page) by making the event listeners not passive and calling `event.preventDefault`

```
function onMouseWheel(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}

function onTouchStart(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}

function onTouchMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...
}

window.addEventListener('wheel', onMouseWheel, {passive: false});
window.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, {passive: false});
window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove, {passive: false});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I aimed to do - it works!! Thank you gman!